# 2D Game Low FPS on iOS - Rendering Debugger settings improves it

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, mobile, urp

I'm encountering low FPS issues on iOS while working on a URP 2D game.

Interestingly, I stumbled upon the Rendering Debugger by accident (through a three-finger tap).
What's peculiar is that when I set the Material Override to Albedo in the Material Filters, it significantly boosts performance by almost 15 FPS.

Could someone kindly elucidate the functionality of this feature and provide guidance on how to implement this substantial improvement in my game? I haven't noticed any discernible visual changes when enabling it.

[image: Profiler]

30 FPS
[image: 30 FPS]

Changing Material Override - Now 52 fps
[image: Changing Material Override - Now 52 fps]

Comment: tbh 30 is not "low" :p at 30 all movement will appear smooth. I cap my 2d games at 30 so as not to waste heat and cycles and battery.  However, if you're overriding the material chances are its using a different shader at a guess. Also by monitoring it, you potentially change the outcome.